# How did they manage to make this song feel speeded?

Tags: technique

I'm a great fan of the Phoenix Wright video game series, and my favourite song is "[Pursuit ~ Cornered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3R8tkvlAlk)", which starts when you show the trial-changing evidence.

When I listen to the song, it always seem to speed up in the middle (Near 50 seconds and following), but as it is meant to be looped, i highly doubt it.

So, I have three questions :

- Is the tempo sped up, and then slowed down ?
- is there a kind of trick to make me think it's sped up ?
- is my ear THAT bad and nothing is sped up ?

Thank you for your attention.

PS : sorry for my english, I'm not sure if "sped up" is right

Comment: Huh. Sounds like an exact repeat of the material before 50 seconds to me. Maybe someone else can hear the difference and can tell you what's happening.

Comment: I haven’t had time to listen to this, but I know that sometimes the introduction of percussion of some sort keeping a steady 2,4 beat gives my ear that impression. It doesn’t mean your ear’s bad; it means it needs more practice. Which is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my metronome, the tempo remains constant, so there is no speeding up.

And according to my ear it doesn't sound sped up at all. I'm in agreement with @Todd on this. There isn't anything happening here speeding the music up or even moving beat emphasis or groove - it really sounds just the same as the music before that point.

Perhaps because you have played that game you associate that point in the piece with something happening? So your anticipation makes you feel the music is faster? I don't know.